# Reading an R plotly object saved as RDS across different systems

Tags: r, plotly

I'm generating `plotly` figures in `R` on my institution's computing cluster and I'd like to be able to view them on my personal mac (e.g., saving a `PDF` or `SVG` static image doesn't work well on the cluster - too many installations involved..).

I thought that saving the `plotly` object to an `RDS` format file, e.g.:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length,
        marker = list(size = 10,
                       color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)',
                       line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                   width = 2))) %>%
  layout(title = 'Styled Scatter',
         yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE),
         xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE))
saveRDS(p,"p.RDS")
```

And then reading it in `RStudio` on my mac shouldn't be a problem. However, when trying to run:

```
readRDS("p.RDS")
```

on my mac's `RStudio`, I get this error:

```
Error in dirname(to) : a character vector argument expected
```

Reading it into a variable:

```
p <- readRDS("p.RDS")
```

does not cause an error so the object is read in successfully but cannot be displayed.

I see that `p$dependencies` shows the path to where `plotly/htmlwidgets/lib/typedarray` is installed on the cluster. Could that be the issue? If so is there anyway to avoid that or change it?

Alternatively, is it possible to simply recreate a plotly object from `p$x`?

Comment: Typo - corrected. Sorry about that.

Comment: It produces the same error message

Comment: What's the difference between saving a single object to an `RDS` and an `RData` format? `RData` would have been relevant if it were multiple objects I was trying to save to a single file. In any case it produces the same error.

Comment: 1. Did you generate the plotly object on a different platform? 2. Are you using R command line or RStudio?

Comment: It only happens to me if the `plotly` object is generated on another computer/platform.

Comment: Hi @dan. Did you manage to find a workaround for this? I am encountering the same problem in my set-up (migrating plotly objects from dev to production server).

Comment: Yes, install the latest plotly package from their github repos' and it should work for you.